# How to get the default TTY font in Unity?

Tags: fonts, tty

I have a simple problem, but the solution is rather difficult to find.

I would like to use the same TTY font in Ubuntu in my GUI environment.

I don't know the name of this font, and I don't know how to set it to my GUI.

I hope you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which font ? Grahical terminal (gnome-terminal or similar) or the console (ctrl-alt-f2 , no GUI )?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i mean the console font. The font which the system start with.

Comment: The console font is in the link I gave you . The font while you boot is in either your bios, grub, or the initramfs, depending on which step you are asking about.